# How to combine search in table by two input text fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

My table looks like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The searching javascript as follows:

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

Look at this example to understand my problem better:

http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/4398/

I filter table rows with the first input field. Then, when I use the second input field, results of first search are not included. How can I fix it?

Comment: What "second input field"?

Comment: @JosephMarikle sorry, I gave a wrong example. I've just updated the question with a right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current logic is a little confused.  You are re-showing and re-hiding the filtered items for every search field.  What you really want is to filter it all in one go like so:

```js
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search1, #search2').on('input', function() {
    var val1 = $.trim($('#search1').val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    var val2 = $.trim($('#search2').val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text1 = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        var text2 = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text1.indexOf(val1) || !~text2.indexOf(val2);
    }).hide();
});
```

```css
body {padding: 20px;}
input {margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 2px 3px; width: 98px;}
td {padding: 4px; border: 1px #CCC solid; width: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search1" placeholder="Type to search">
<input type="text" id="search2" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="table">
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

That's of course assuming non-dynamic number of columns and filter fields.  If that's what you're after, you need to check the index rather than hard coding `td:nth-child(1)` and `td:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 4):

When you are applying your filter, you are first showing all the rows, negating any previous filtering on them. This is one solution to that problem... it stores the filters and applies both on either input's keyup event, based on your fiddle.

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
var filters = { col1: '', col2: ''};
$('#search1').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    filters.col1 = val;
    applyFilters();
});
$('#search2').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    filters.col2 = val;
    applyFilters();
});
function applyFilters() {
    $rows.show();
  $rows.filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(filters.col1);
    }).hide();
  $rows.filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(filters.col2);
    }).hide();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it using `each()`. This code will collect the value of each input for each `keyup()`, then if this value exists in the corresponding `td` by using `indexOf()`, it will show the `tr` which contains this `td` and hide others, otherwise it will show all `tr`'s

http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/4399/

```js
var $rows = $('#table tr'),
    searchVal1,
    searchVal2,
    td1,
    td2;

$('input').keyup(function () {
  searchVal1 = $('#search1').val(),
  searchVal2 = $('#search2').val();

  $rows.each(function (index, tr) {
    td1 = $(tr).find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text().toLowerCase(),
    td2 = $(tr).find('td:nth-of-type(2)').text().toLowerCase();

    if ( (td1.indexOf(searchVal1) != -1) && (td2.indexOf(searchVal2) != -1) ) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

  if ((searchVal1 === '') && (searchVal2 === '')) {
    $rows.show();
  }
});
```

```css
body {padding: 20px;}
input {margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 2px 3px; width: 98px;}
td {padding: 4px; border: 1px #CCC solid; width: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search1" placeholder="Type to search">
<input type="text" id="search2" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="table">
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```