# theads disappears when searching in table html

Tags: javascript, html

Can you check this code form me I'm trying to get individual search for every columun and this code is working, the problem is when I search theads disapears.

```
<style>
body {padding: 20px;}
input {margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 2px 3px; width: 98px;}
td {padding: 4px; border: 1px #CCC solid; width: 100px;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search1" placeholder="Type to search">
<input type="text" id="search2" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>Item</tr>
        <tr>Color</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Green</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Grapes</td>
            <td>Green</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is the searching script.

```
<script>
var $rows = $('#table tr'),
    searchVal1,
    searchVal2,
    td1,
    td2;

$('input').keyup(function () {
  searchVal1 = $('#search1').val(),
  searchVal2 = $('#search2').val();

  $rows.each(function (index, tr) {
    td1 = $(tr).find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text().toLowerCase(),
    td2 = $(tr).find('td:nth-of-type(2)').text().toLowerCase();

    if ( (td1.indexOf(searchVal1) != -1) && (td2.indexOf(searchVal2) != -1) ) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

  if ((searchVal1 === '') && (searchVal2 === '')) {
    $rows.show();
  }
});
</script>
```

I got the code from this question : [How to combine search in table by two input text fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687616/how-to-combine-search-in-table-by-two-input-text-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that with `$('#table tr')` you are getting all rows from the table, including the first one (table headers). You should exclude it.

```js
<script>
var $rows = $('#table tr:not(:first)'),
    searchVal1,
    searchVal2,
    td1,
    td2;

$('input').keyup(function () {
  searchVal1 = $('#search1').val(),
  searchVal2 = $('#search2').val();

  $rows.each(function (index, tr) {
    td1 = $(tr).find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text().toLowerCase(),
    td2 = $(tr).find('td:nth-of-type(2)').text().toLowerCase();

    if ( (td1.indexOf(searchVal1) != -1) && (td2.indexOf(searchVal2) != -1) ) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

  if ((searchVal1 === '') && (searchVal2 === '')) {
    $rows.show();
  }
});
</script>
```

Another approach is to use `$('#table tbody tr')` - to get all rows inside tbody (without the header row)

Also, use `<th>` instead of `<tr>` for table headers

Comment: If my solution helped you, please mark it as accepted